# Why calls from the same client are not executed at the same time

Tags: c#, azure-functions, httpclient

I have azure function that only have 2 lines of code, first is await Task.Delay(5000) and second is returning status Ok to client. In host.json maxOutstandingRequests and maxConcurrentRequests are set. AF is executed locally and also i tried with deployed version. The problem occurs when I try to send multiple requests from the same HttpClient, function calls will not be async. Execution time per call will be 5, 10, 15, 20 and 25s. When i run same client's code with WebApi instead of AF (WebApi controller has same function as AF), then execution time per each call is 5s. I want to know how can i get the same behavior with Azure function as I have it with WebApi?

Below I provided client's code.

```
class Program
{
       private static System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           IEnumerable<TimeSpan> result = Test(10);

           Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", result));
           Console.ReadLine();
       }

       private static IEnumerable<TimeSpan> Test(int taskCount)
       {
           Task<TimeSpan>[] tasks = new Task<TimeSpan>[taskCount];

           for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
                tasks[i] = Send();

           Task.WaitAll(tasks);

           return tasks.Select(t => t.Result);
       }

       private static async Task<TimeSpan> Send()
       {
           using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AF"]))
           {
                Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

                sw.Start();

                using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request))
                {
                    sw.Stop();

                    return sw.Elapsed;
                }
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: How does the code in the function look like?

Comment: And the values for `maxOutstandingRequests` and `maxConcurrentRequest`?

Comment: @Turbo

    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> 
    Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = 
    "AF")]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
    {
            await Task.Delay(5 * 1000);

            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

Comment: @Turbo Values are 50

Answer (score 1):

I did some research for this issue. First, I added a line of code in your client's code "Console.WriteLine("--" + sw.Elapsed);".

[image]

Then run this code and I saw the 10 Stopwatch start time are printed at the same time.

[image]

So this is the reason for the result of 5s, 10s, 15s, 20s and 25s.

After that, if we want to test the async task of azure function, we must add the property in host.json(I think you have completed it)

[image]

And then I run the client's code in visual studio and got the result as below screenshot.

[image]

I'm not sure if you have the same problem. If you met the same problem as the screenshot above shows. You can install Fiddler4(because according to some research, it may caused by proxy). So I installed Fiddler4 and then run the client's code in visual studio again.
It shows the code send 10 requests successfully and the sw.Elapsed time returned are what we expected.

[image]

The 10 lines of 6.xx seconds prove the azure function run task async.

Comment: 6.5s is much time. Our AF sleeps 5s so we expect that result per call to be up to ~5.5s. If we run same clien's code for WebApi we will have result ~5.5s or if we change our client's code that it uses new HttpClient for each call instead of one static HttpClient, we will have result ~5.5s with AF. I want to get result ~5.5s with one static HttpClient as with WebApi.

Comment: Latency is there. Did you check the region where you are hosting AF?

Comment: @ImranArshad Yes, I did. I can get result ~5.5s if I use new HttpClient for each call but I want to use one static HttpClient.

Comment: Hi @hehe, I changed the location to be the same as my AF and test it. The results are 5.6~5.7 seconds.

Comment: @HuryShen Results are ~5.5s. I ran two times client's code and results were 6-7s but after second running results are ~5.5s. Sorry I did not check it multiple times before I wrote comment. I have two questions about this solution. 1. If i change taskCount from 10 to eg 500(maxOutstandingRequests and maxConcurrentRequest are also changed), results will be ~10s. Why? 2. Can we get same behavior without fiddler because it is client's code and cliens will not have fiddler? Can we change AF settings that it can receive requests from one HttpClient or can we change client to work without fiddler?